# Route mail from Postfix to SMTP Relay and Back

Tags: email, postfix

I'm having an issue routing mail in the following scenario:

Inbound:

Internet > Postfix > Third Party Filtering > Postfix > Mailbox

The key thing to note is that the message leaves my postfix server, goes to my third party filtering, and is sent back to postfix and *should* be delivered to my mailbox.

However, it looks like its just looping back to the filtering service until it bounces due to too many hops. I'm trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this.

I've tried doing this using the following transport map:

```
2.2.2.2/32 local
example.com mail.smarthost.com
```

2.2.2.2 would be the IP the message is sent from the filtering service to my postfix server.

I've also tried doing this via a header check:

```
/^header_value_added_by_mail_service$/ FILTER local
/^generic_header_value$/ FILTER smtp:mail.smarthost.com
```

No matter what I do, the message continues to loop between Postfix and the mail filtering service. I guess if I better understood which option takes precedence this might click. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is Postfix after queue filtering by utilizing the the **content_filter** parameter as described in the http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html.
You would have to make sure that the 3rd party filtering can submit mail back to your Postfix on another port (ans you would need to create a corresponding entry in master.cf for it)